# Are throttleable rocket engines the less efficient the lower the power setting?

Tags: engine, engine-design, throttle, rocket

Are throttleable rocket engines less efficient the lower the power setting? Logically that would lead to lower pressures in combustion chamber and so lower thermodynamic efficiency. Or is it remedied by combustion chamber design?

Comment: Did you perhaps mean to post this on space.stackexchange.com?

Comment: There are numerous questions here about engines, and this is pertaining to rocket powered interceptors, I think it fits here. It's not  usual to throttle spacegoing rockets save for vernier engines

Comment: You've just posted a [question about jet engines](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28153/12102) in Space SE and here's a question about rocket engines in Aviation SE. I'm voting to close both and hopefully you'll get both of them in the right location. If these *are* the right locations, there won't be further votes and mine will expire. By the way these days practically all rocket engines going to space are throttle-able, and a quick check of questions in Space SE will show this. This shows 200 posts: https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=throttle